# File Upload Failing with "Invalid stream or file provided " in laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-7

I try is to submit data with a file passport access token using postman I am getting below errors saying: "Invalid stream reference provided" my code is running in PHP 7.3, Laravel7 on IIS server.

> ```sh
> [2020-06-15 12:56:14] local.ERROR: Invalid stream reference provided {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Diactoros\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Invalid stream reference provided at C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\passport_demo\\vendor\\laminas\\laminas-diactoros\\src\\Stream.php:345)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok after tracing the issue all the way back to \SplFileInfo I found that IIS had to write permission to C:\Windows\Temp, but not read permission. So the file would arrive properly and then not be readable into Zend\Diactoros\UploadedFile.

If anyone else runs into a 500 with "Invalid stream or the file provided for UploadedFile" check permissions on the folder IIS/PHP is uploading to.